# Using higher-ranked trait bounds with generics

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've stumbled upon an interesting edge case: using higher-ranked lifetime bounds to accept closures that return generic parameters, such as `for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> R: MyTrait`. There's no way to specify that `R` lives for at most `'a`. Perhaps it's best to explain with an example.

Let's define a simple reference-like type wrapping a value:

```rust
struct Source;

struct Ref<'a> {
    source: &'a Source,
    value: i32,
}
```

For convenience, let's add a helper constructor. Here I will use explicit lifetimes to make the borrowing self-explanatory:

```rust
impl Source {
    fn new_ref<'a>(&'a self, value: i32) -> Ref<'a> {
        Ref { source: self, value }
    }
}
```

This is an extremely fancy implementation of a integer copying routine using HRTBs with a closure over our `Ref`:

```rust
fn call_1<F>(callback: F) -> i32
where
    for<'a> F: FnOnce(&'a Source) -> Ref<'a>,
{
    let source = Source;
    callback(&source).value
}

fn fancy_copy_1(value: i32) -> i32 {
    call_1(|s| s.new_ref(value))
}
```

This is fine and is working as expected. We know that `Ref` does not outlive the `Source` and the compiler is also able to pick it up. Now let's create a simple trait and implement it for our reference:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn value(&self) -> i32;
}

impl<'a> MyTrait for Ref<'a> {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.value
    }
}
```

And modify our integer copying routine to return a generic type implementing that trait instead of just returning `Ref`:

```rust
fn call_2<R, F>(callback: F) -> i32
where
    for<'a> F: FnOnce(&'a Source) -> R,
    R: MyTrait,
{
    let source = Source;
    callback(&source).value()
}

fn fancy_copy_2(value: i32) -> i32 {
    call_2(|s| s.new_ref(value))
}
```

Suddenly I get an error: `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements`. [Rust playground link for convenience](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0120d3dcaa3a5d72ffdee9e0d1694351). That actually makes sense from some perspective: unlike with `Ref<'a>` in the first example I never said that `R` has to live for at most `'a`. could very well live longer and thus have access to freed memory. So I need to annotate it with it's own lifetime. But there's no place to do it! The first instinct is to put the lifetime in the bounds:

```rust
where
    for<'a> F: FnOnce(&'a Source) -> R,
    R: MyTrait + 'a,
```

which is of course incorrect, as `'a` is only defined for the first bound.

This is where I got confused, started searching and never found anything about combining HRTBs and generic types in one bound. Perhaps more experienced people in Rust have any suggestions?

Upd 1.

While I was thinking about the problem some more, I remembered I could use the `impl Trait` syntax. This looks like a solution to my problem:

```rust
fn call_3<F>(callback: F) -> i32
where
     F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Source) -> (impl MyTrait + 'a),
{
    let source = Source;
    callback(&source).value()
}

fn fancy_copy_3(value: i32) -> i32 {
    call_3(|s| Box::new(s.new_ref(value)))
}
```

That, however does not work because `impl MyTrait` is not allowed in this place for some reason (probably temporarily). But that made me think of `dyn Trait` syntax and that indeed does work!

```rust
fn call_4<F>(callback: F) -> i32
where
     F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Source) -> Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>,
{
    let source = Source;
    let value = callback(&source); // note how a temporary is required
    value.value()
}

fn fancy_copy_4(value: i32) -> i32 {
    call_4(|s| Box::new(s.new_ref(value)))
}
```

Here's my solution: with  `dyn Trait` syntax there is a place to put the `+ 'a`! Unfortunately this solution still doesn't quite work for me too well, as it requires object-safety on the trait plus adds an overhead of allocating a boxed value. But at least it's something.